# parse text file and convert to json and append data from loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a scenario where I am running command which generates a text file (demo.txt) data as below:

```
{
  "id" : "aaaaaaaabhikz75nc3wkao54xhuv245ye6zmjhcecralymbjo3hhvh5qtugq",
  "name" : "zsssd",
  "description" : "testfiler",
  "ticket" : null,
  "cId" : "yu2tiwguc45t6t5ej25pfzpevfhpcbbjjxjjvw6wa",
  "createdBy" : null,
  "timeCreated" : null
}{
  "id" : "aaaaaaaabhikz75nc3wkao54xhuv245ye",
  "name" : "klsssd",
  "description" : "testfiler2",
  "ticket" : null,
  "cId" : "yu2tiwguc456wa",
  "createdBy" : null,
  "timeCreated" : 107635378859
}
```

I want to convert the same into json and extract the information about the name and append `flp` (refer code below) value to it while its running in each loop and store it in a dict.

below is what I have tried

```
flp = ["modeltf","modeltz"]
for r in flp:
    res = subprocess.call(['java', '-jar','dem.jar', 'dataname', '-o', 'demo.txt', '-f', r])
    with open('demo.txt') as in, with open('demo.json','w') as out:
         json_string = json.dumps(in, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

this did not work as expected, any leads would be great

desired results : `[{"name" : "zsssd", "flp" : "modeltf"}, {"name" : "klsssd", "flp" : "modeltz"}]`

as first loop runs for `modeltf` next it runs for `modeltz`

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
flp = ["modeltf","modeltz"]
for r in flp:
    res = subprocess.call(['java', '-jar','dem.jar', 'dataname', '-o', 'demo.txt', '-f', r])
    with open("namespaces.txt") as f:
        demo = f.read().replace("\n","")
        records = re.findall(r"\{[^\}]*\}", demo)
        dictionaries = [json.loads(r) for r in records] # this creates the dictonary out of the demo.txt file.
```

Now I am trying to get the names from the list dictionary and trying to map it with the flp items to get this result.
`[{"name" : "zsssd", "flp" : "modeltf"}, {"name" : "klsssd", "flp" : "modeltz"}]`

using :

```
results = [{"name": name, "flp": flp} for name,flp in zip(names, flp)]
```

but it doesn't loop through the complete data and ouputs only the first dict item.

Comment: How are the strings "testfiler" and "testfiler2" supposed to move from the "description" to the "name" key and how are the other keys in the input file supposed to not be in the result? There isn't any code which tries to do that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 my bad, that was a typo, I have rectified it

Comment: "this did not work as expected" What are your actual results? What do you think is going wrong, based on your own attempt to diagnose the problem?

Comment: What is the importance of the `flp` values? I don't see anything in your code that uses them.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel using `flp` values I am looping and passing as input to the subprocess call. I edited the question

Comment: @KarlKnechtel problem is i do not know how would I approach the solution for my desired results, need some help there

Comment: What part of "what are your actual results" was unclear? *What happens when you try using your code*? How is that different from the "desired results:" that you showed?

Comment: @karl knechtel I am able to convert the txt into json, problem currently with code is I am not able to map the results of the json with the loop I am running. Edited the code which I am using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236018/discussion-between-alex-and-karl-knechtel).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import json

results = []

flp = ["modeltf","modeltz"]
for r in flp:
    res = subprocess.call(['java', '-jar','dem.jar', 'dataname', '-o', 'demo.txt', '-f', r])
    with open("namespaces.txt") as f:
        demo = f.read().replace("\n","")
        records = re.findall(r"\{[^\}]*\}", demo)
        dictionaries = [json.loads(r) for r in records] # this creates the dictonary out of the demo.txt file.

        for dictionary in dictionaries:

            # option 1, return dictionaries with only 'name' and 'flp' keys
            # 
            result = {"name": dictionary.get(name), "flp": r}
            results.append(result)

            # option 2, return the dictionaries with all the keys
            # 
            # dictionary["flp"] = r
            # results.append(dictionary)
```

Comment: Thanks , it solves the part of getting the txt file converted to JSON but for the next part it returns only one mapping, it doesn't iterate through loop

Comment: Ok, I edit the answer also. Once you have the dictionaries from the demo.txt output, you only have to include the "flp" key-value on them, and append them in a results list...

Comment: If you only need "name" and "flp" keys, you could create a new dictionary and append it instead of the loaded one...

Comment: It takes too long for a bigger set of data (6k records)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer deserves a negative vote... and why you don't consider it correct...

Comment: I have not voted as negative, it works as exepcted but for more records its not suitable.